# Google cloud API gateway Override Request Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, api-gateway, google-api-gateway

Is there any way I can rename request parameters at API gateway itself instead of changing cloud function code, like appVersion to app_version

In AWS api gateway I had used requestTemplates of [x-amazon-apigateway-integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html)

Comment: No, you can't translate the headers key to something else.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I mean , request body parameters

Comment: You also can't. in the API spec file, you can define the required fields in your body, but you can't get them with the name A and forward them to the backend with the name B. To perform these advanced things, you can use APIGee, but it's not the same cost!